# How to specify a local file within html using the file: scheme?

Tags: html, url, file-uri

I'm loading a html file hosted on the OS X built in Apache server, within that file I am linking to another html file in the same directory as follows:

```
<a href="2ndFile.html"><button type="submit">Local file</button>
```

This works. However (for reasons too lengthy to go into) I am experimenting using the file: scheme instead, however I cannot get anything to work. Here is how I am re-writing the above line using file:

```
<a href="file://192.168.1.57/~User/2ndFile.html"><button type="submit">Local file</button>
```

(192.168.1.57 is my current IP address)

Changing it to the following does also not work:

```
<a href="file://Name-Of-MacBookPro/~User/2ndFile.html"><button type="submit">Local file</button>
```

But the file cannot be found, how should it be specified using the file: scheme?

Comment: Unless I missed something, file:// Points to a file on the client machine... So if you are trying to get a file that is on the server, you should keep using HTTP...

Comment: None of your examples finish with </a>.  So, all the html for the rest of the doc is included in the link.  And, maybe other complications i can only imagine.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The `file:` URL scheme refers to a file on the client machine. There is no hostname in the `file:` scheme; you just provide the path of the file. So, the file on your local machine would be `file:///~User/2ndFile.html`. Notice the three slashes; the hostname part of the URL is empty, so the slash at the beginning of the path immediately follows the double slash at the beginning of the URL. You will also need to expand the user's path; `~` does no expand in a `file:` URL. So you would need `file:///home/User/2ndFile.html` (on most Unixes), `file:///Users/User/2ndFile.html` (on Mac OS X), or `file:///C:/Users/User/2ndFile.html` (on Windows).

Many browsers, for security reasons, do not allow linking from a file that is loaded from a server to a local file. So, you may not be able to do this from a page loaded via HTTP; you may only be able to link to `file:` URLs from other local pages.

Comment: how to use **relative path** instead of C:// on Windows?

Comment: To use a relative path, you just include the relative path, without any `file:` scheme or `//`. So if you have a file `index.html`, and want to refer to `other_file.html` in the same directory, you would just link directly to `other_file.html` with no scheme.

Comment: @Brian then there is no any way to download local file like file:///home/User/2ndFile.html ? I would like to know if there is any alternative available?

Answer (score 4):

The 'file' protocol is not a network protocol. Therefore file://192.168.1.57/~User/2ndFile.html simply does not make much sense.

Question is how you load the first file. Is that really done using a web server? Does not really sound like. If it is, then why not use the same protocol, most likely http? You cannot expect to simply switch the protocol and use two different protocols the same way...

I suspect the first file is not really loaded using an apache http server at all, but simply by opening the file? href="2ndFile.html" simply works because it uses a "relative url". This makes the browser use the same protocol and path as where he got the first (current) file from.

Comment: The first file is loaded by a client application, the reason I'm using file:// is I'm experimenting with some security stuff and seeing if its possible for the first file to use file://.

Comment: Well that's all fine (the little you tell). But if you use the file protocol this has _nothing_ to do with apache. Apache is a http server.

Comment: I realize that when this answer was written it may have not been the case: The `file` _scheme_ is one of the schemes mentioned in the [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738/) and defined in [RFC8089](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089). The [URL Living Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) has examples using the `file` scheme.

Comment: @OrestisKapar It was the case, but none of that is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

the "file://" url protocol can only be used to locate files in the file system of the local machine.  since this html code is interpreted by a browser, the "local machine" is the machine that is running the browser.

if you are getting file not found errors, i suspect it is because the file is not found. however, it could also be a security limitation of the browser. some browsers will not let you reference a filesystem file from a non-filesystem html page. you could try using the file path from the command line on the machine running the browser to confirm that this is a browser limitation and not a legitimate missing file.

Comment: Yeah, there's no way a remote webpage would be allowed to use file: protocol. 
 If so, any hacker could snoop around in your filesystem, just by getting you to surf to their page where they used those urls.  Like file:///Users/turner/ might be your home directory, and file:///etc/passwd would be the list of all users on your machine, and file:///etc/ssh would have info on how to log in to your machine with ssh.  (depends on your OS but easy to guess.). If this was EVER allowed, they probably prohibited it by 2000 in all browsers.  No, no, no.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue before and in my case the file was in another machine
so i have mapped network drive z  to the folder location where my file is
then i created a context in tomcat 


so in my web project i could access the HTML file via context

Comment: Did you check if you proposed solution works? If not, I recommend you do not post the answer, since it might mislead others.

Comment: Yes worked for me long time ago..editing my comment  for more details

Comment: this should work `file://///ComputerNameOnNetwork/DriveLetter/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

For apache look up SymLink or you can solve via the OS with Symbolic Links or on linux set up a library link/etc

My answer is one method specifically to windows 10.

So my method involves mapping a network drive to U:/ (e.g. I use G:/ for Google Drive)

open `cmd` and type `hostname` (example result: `LAPTOP-G666P000`, you could use your ip instead, but using a static hostname for identifying yourself makes more sense if your network stops)

Press `Windows_key + E` > `right click 'This PC'` > press `N`
(It's Map Network drive, NOT add a network location)

If you are right clicking the shortcut on the desktop you need to press N then enter

Fill out `U:` or `G:` or `Z:` or whatever you want
Example Address: `\\LAPTOP-G666P000\c$\Users\username\`

Then you can use `<a href="file:///u:/2ndFile.html"><button type="submit">Local file</button>` like in your question

---

related: You can also use this method for FTPs, and setup multiple drives for different relative paths on that same network.

related2: I have used `http://localhost/c$` etc before on some WAMP/apache servers too before, you can use `.htaccess` for control/security but I recommend to not do so on a live/production machine -- or any other symlink documentroot example you can google