# How change icon Marker Gmap Primefaces?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jsf-2, primefaces

Hello community I'm starting with Gmap Primefaces component, and want to know how to change the icons.
I have relied on the showcase of Primefaces:

```
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", "konyaalti.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki", "ataturkparki.png"));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "kaleici.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png"));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "karaalioglu.png", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png"));
```

I've downloaded the icons to my project, and I've routed, but just does not work and marker icons are samples.

```
StringBuilder ruta = new StringBuilder();
ruta.append(getContext().getRealPath(Constantes.DIVISOR));
ruta.append("resources/maps/images/");

StringBuilder bluedot = new StringBuilder(); 
bluedot.append(ruta);
bluedot.append("blue-dot");
bluedot.append(Constantes.EXTENSION_FORMATO_PNG);

StringBuilder pinkdot = new StringBuilder(); 
pinkdot.append(ruta);
pinkdot.append("pink-dot");
pinkdot.append(Constantes.EXTENSION_FORMATO_PNG);

StringBuilder yellowdot = new StringBuilder(); 
yellowdot.append(ruta);
yellowdot.append("yellow-dot");
yellowdot.append(Constantes.EXTENSION_FORMATO_PNG);

System.out.println("---> "+bluedot.toString());

//Icons and Data
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", "konyaalti.png", bluedot.toString()));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki", "ataturkparki.png"));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "kaleici.png", pinkdot.toString()));
this.advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "karaalioglu.png", yellowdot.toString()));
```

Being well the image file path, but still does not consider the Marker PrimeFaces, to which it should be ???

```
Console:

D:\springsource\apache tomcat 7.0.53\webapps\geotermica\resources\maps\images\blue-dot.png
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to point to a file on your file system you should use the `file://` scheme. See: [How to specify a local file within html using the file: scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme)

If you want to create a relative URL to fetch the image from your webserver you should use the [context path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) instead of the real path:

```
StringBuilder ruta = new StringBuilder();
ruta.append(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath());
ruta.append("/resources/maps/images/");
```

Comment: I can't make it works. Seems that works only with Google URL.

Comment: If you paste the resulting URL in your browser and an image is loaded, this should work. You should end up with something like `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/resources/maps/images/yourimage.png`

Comment: I just solved using this simple string:   markerType.add("./resources/red-dot.png");

Comment: Check if you are using the correct constructor and parameters: `Marker(LatLng latlng, String title, Object data, String icon)`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I used it to contact a reverse proxy within the same application.