# Downloading a file using a file url

Tags: html

#### click here to download :

Download image

```
<a href="C:/Users/user/Desktop/Strectching.jpg" target="_blank" download="Stretching.jpg">Download image</a>
```

When I try download the file within the folder that the html code is found, it works perfectly. But when I specify a specific URL, then it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Strectching.jpg" target="_blank" download="Stretching.jpg">Download image</a>
```

It will open the file in a new tab and there you can download it. If the extension of the file is not familiar with the browser, it will prompt you whether to download it or open it with an application

Answer (score 1):

Try using File URI scheme.

Something like file://c/users/user/Desktop/Strectching.jpg

Im not sure for synthax now on Windows but it should be like i wrote below

Comment: I tried using the File URI Scheme. When I open the image in firefox using the File URI scheme, it works. But when I insert it into the code, it does not work.

Comment: Did you try following solution in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme