# omouseover not working for images at my machine though it works for online images

Tags: html

This is working in my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://nineplanets.org/planets.jpg" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://nineplanets.org/planetorder.JPG';"
onmouseout="this.src='http://nineplanets.org/planets.jpg';">
</img>

</body>
</html>
```

But this is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\WE\Pics\milk.png"
onmouseover="this.src='C:\Users\user\Desktop\WE\Pics\butter.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='C:\Users\user\Desktop\WE\Pics\milk.png';">
</img>

</body>
</html>
```

Please answer as soon as possible and path to my images is totally correct!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use paths pointing to your local hard drive, you will need to use the file protocol like this:

```
file:///c:/Users/user/Desktop/WE/Pics/milk.png
```

However, it's best practice to use relative URLs instead, for instance:

```
Pics/milk.png
```

will find the file `milk.png` in the `Pics` folder, where the `Pics` folder is alongside your HTML file.

Comment: hey! could you please justify as why do we need this file protocol type as you mentioned above in your answer?

Comment: @GuneetKaur As far as I know it's just one of the quirks (features?) of HTML. The file URL makes it so that there is a standardized URL format whether you're on Windows, Mac OS, Linux, etc.. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12711835/2234742) and [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use paths pointing to a local hard drive. That would be a major security issue. you will have to either mount a localhost server or try using the `file://` protocol.

Comment: but i used the same path for simple command i.e. <img src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\WE\Pics\milk.png" >                                                      and that works perfectly.