# Media file location

Tags: html

I have made a download link, but can't keep everything on my (C:) drive, so I put the media files on my (F:) drive, but when I go to download it, or try to play it I get a message that says:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

this is the code, but for it to let me download anything I have to take (F:) out. Doing THAT just lets me download an error message. If I don't do anything different its just completely unresponsive.

```
<h1>Videos</h1>
    <h3>Big Hero 6</h3>
        <video width="320" height="240" poster="Videos/Poster/Big Hero 6 Poster.jpg" controls> 
            <source src="F:/Videos/Movies/Big Hero 6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <mark>Video Not Supported</mark>
        </video>
    <a href="F:/Videos/Movies/Big Hero 6.mp4" download><button>Download</button></a>
```

I also tried changing it to,

(file://f:/Videos/Movies/Big Hero 6.mp4)(F://Videos/Movies/Big Hero 6.mp4)

I have no idea what i did wrong?

Comment: `src` and `href` expect to get full URLs. If you want to provide a URL to a local file, it needs to be prefixed with `file:`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme for more details. However even then this might not work, since we don't know where/how you are actually serving the HTML document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a local file within html using the file: scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme)