# I have a file at a (LOCAL) location in my system other than fitness folder and need to show hyperlink to download that file from FITNESSE wiki

Tags: java, fixtures, fitnesse

In Fitnesse wiki how do i allow file Download. I have a file on a location in my local which i am trying to pass it to fitnesse wiki. 
{{{"TEST"; }}}
Using this i am able to pass Anchor tag to wiki screen but when i click on it nothing happens. I am not sure y this happens in fitnesse.

i have tried using Object and Embed HTML tags options those are not working at all. i need to show a hyperlink of file and make it downloadable to user who runs fitnesse test.

"TEST";

FILE should get downloaded via browser it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is just 'normal' browser behaviour. The FitNesse page is loaded via `http://` and therefore the browser will not open any `file://` links. See for instance [How to specify a local file within html using the file: scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme)

FitNesse will serve files located in its 'files-section' over http, so they can be accessed.

A workaround that you could consider is: make some code (in a fixture) to copy the file from its current location into the files section and then link to it there (using a http link).