# Is this a relative path or an absolute path?

Tags: java, javafx, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm having a little difficulty determining if the path in the code below is a relative path or an absolute path. Also, in this case, I'm trying to open an image  I placed inside a folder called *"img"* which is inside my java project directory. Please don't mind the double backslash (\), I know these only works on Windows, the only thing I wanted to ask if this path relative or absolute.

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(new Image("file:img\\square.png"))
```

Comment: Looks relative to me, but I'm not familiar with `ImageView`

Comment: It is relative path~

Comment: It is neither. It is a relative URL with invalid characters.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is to open an image inside my current java project directory, so is it still an URL? I also know that I used double backslash (\\) in the path which only works on Windows but other than that, is this path a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

As you can find in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) you can pass to the constructor any URL supported by the [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class, which is the case in your example.

If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm quite new so from what I understand then since the URL I provided is not a valid URL so the image is searched on the specified path instead, but does the path be classified as relative or absolute?

Answer (score -2):

In your case, it is relative.

> The file: URL scheme refers to a file on the client machine. There is no hostname in the file: scheme; you just provide the path of the file. So, the file on your local machine would be file:///~User/2ndFile.html.

Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711584/how-to-specify-a-local-file-within-html-using-the-file-scheme) for further information.

Comment: It is relative to the current working directory, not the user's home directory. The answer you are quoting from is about a URL that already contains `~User`. Your link is to a question, not an answer.