# Can't find image in CSS

Tags: css, image

I tried to put an image named "books.jpg" on the background of my page but it says that it can't find it!However,I am sure that the link to the image is correct.

````
    background-image: url('/Users/abdulazizsuleymanov/Desktop/Python/Django/Review-book/books.jpg');
    /*background-color: #cccccc;*/
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;```[css file][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O1Ff.png
````

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12711584/82548

Comment: in static/css/style.css

Comment: Wrong path .....

Comment: Put your image to the `reviews/static/images` folder and on your CSS file use `../images/books.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it directly in the same folder? That way you can just use url('./books.jpg')

Comment: I did everything you said but it still can't find it

Answer (score 0):

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style
> sheet, not relative to the document
> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1#url

It's easiest if you just put the image near the css file.